# How to install a UWP application on an ARM device without packing the application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am developing a UWP application in C# for a device with ARM architecture. The OS version of the device is 10.0.10586.494. Visual Studio won't let me create an application package because the minimum version is too old.

I can install the application having the device connected to the pc from Visual Studio compiling in debug device. But if I don't have the device and I compile in release arm, the files generated in the arm's bin folder then how would it be installed on the device?

Greetings and thank you

Comment: You need a compatible driver.  Old drivers that were built before WinXP cannot be used directly by c# and need a c++ wrapper to be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault.
Visual Studio let me create the package, I got a warning but it let me continue creating the package.

Regards